# In WordPress, after installing "Pie Register" plugin, admin permission is GONE!

Tags: plugins, debug

After installing the [Pie Register](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/) plugin to my WordPress (v4.2.2) site, I found my administrator user lost all its administrative permissions. The menus for viewing and changing the site configurations, themes etc. are all invisible.  So I can't even disable the plugin as admin user.

I have since logged in the MySQL database, and deleted all the rows starting with 'pie' from the `wp_options` table, and deleted the directory `wp-content/plugins/pie-register` and relogging in with the admin user, but it still doesn't work.

How can I recover from this state?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the plugin but following function could solve your problem,
Add the following code-snippet(function) to functions.php.
 *After creating the new admin, use the credentials as given by yourself.*

> It does **not** recover the state of wp nor your admin user but this function creates a new admin user. So you are able *(only when there is/was no other reason then that plugin you deleted which maybe causes all trouble)* to login as admin with the capabilities which belong to that user role.

```
function add_new_admin_account_195142(){
$login = 'newadmin'; // Create/Use an unique name
$passw = 'newpassword'; // Create unique pw
$email = 'newadmin@myourdomain.com'; //Use unique email address

    if ( !username_exists( $login )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $login, $passw, $email );
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $user->set_role( 'administrator' );
    }
}
add_action('init','add_new_admin_account_195142');
```

> I have no idea what the reason was/is that a plugin would/could do such so I am not 100% sure if you succeed.(normally it should do the trick imho)

Comment: Now it shows `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/qazwsx/mysiteroot/post/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4828`

Comment: The error disappears as soon you remove the function which I created for you?

Comment: As soon as I comment out the last line.

Comment: What does line 4828 say/show? in that file here it is a start for a function (Delete a file), and that would be weird. Did you copy 1 on 1 the function as shown by me?

Comment: It would also be nice to see what your debug.log shows. Activate it by adding following code in wp-config.php `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and `@ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );`.